# Script for looping through multiple spreadsheets doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a script to loop through multiple spreadsheets for 2 purposes.

- The first is '.setNumberFormat'.
- The second is to find the lookup date and '.setUnprotectedRanges'.

The problem is my script ran but didn't do anything.

Because I'm just a starter who learn to make a script.(My basic of coding is zero.) I don't know why my script didn't do anything.

Any some advice would be highly appreciated.

```
function myFunction() {
var idSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('myspreadsheetID').getSheetByName('คีย์บัญชี');
var todayDate = new Date();
todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var last7DaysDate = new Date();
last7DaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
last7DaysDate.setDate(todayDate.getDate()-7);

for(var x=4;x<=6;x++){
var id = idSheet.getRange(x, 2).getValue();

var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var ss = s.getSheetByName('คีย์บัญชี');

//set format วันที่ ตัวอย่างเช่น พฤ. 26
var rangeToFormat = ss.getRange('C2:C');
rangeToFormat.setNumberFormat('ddd D');

var data = ss.getRange('C1:C').getValues();  

for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
  var fDate = new Date(data[i]);
  if (fDate.getDate() == last7DaysDate.getDate() && 
      fDate.getMonth() == last7DaysDate.getMonth() && 
      fDate.getFullYear() == last7DaysDate.getFullYear()) {

        var protection = ss.protect();  
        var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
        var unprotected1 = ss.getRange(i+1,3,lastRow-i,7); //คีย์รายการขาย
        var unprotected2 = ss.getRange('X10:AB25'); //ประวัติการตัดยอดฝาก
        var unprotected3 = ss.getRange('X31:AB41'); //ค่าใช้จ่ายประจำเดือน
        protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected1,unprotected2,unprotected3]);
      }
}

}

}
```

Comment: Even for a single column or row Range.getValues() returns a nested array. data[i] is an array. data[i][0] is the cell content you want. (number in the first bracket is row second is column, 0 referenced and therefore a comon source of off by one errors)

Range.setNumberFormat(Object[][]) takes a 2 dimesnional array of the same bounds as the range. 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

สวัสดีครับคุณน้อง

This *does* work.

First, check to make sure that you have permissions to edit the spreadsheets.

Check that you're using the correct `id`. Try inserting `Logger.log()` statements to see what values the script is working with.

```
for(var x=4;x<=6;x++){
  var id = idSheet.getRange(x, 2).getValue();
  Logger.log("x: " x + "ID: " + id);
  ...
}
```

Run the script, then view the Logs

[image]

Next, check your condition values. Use `Logger.log()` again. Specifically, check `last7DaysDate`:

```
Logger.log("Last7Date: " + last7DaysDate.getDate() + "/" + (last7DaysDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + last7DaysDate.getFullYear())
```

Note that the value of `.getMonth()` is zero-indexed, so you should add 1 to *display* the expected value.

Then, look at the date values that you're comparing against.

```
Logger.log("fDate: "+ fDate.getDate() + "/" + (fDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + fDate.getFullYear());
```

I ran your script after making changes only to the protected ranges `X10:AB25` and `X31:AB41`. It ran without errors, changed the formatting, and set the sheet protections.

[image]

โชคดีนะครับ